# Option for hibernate in power menu missing

Tags: windows-10, hibernate

I've red other answers and can't seem to get it working. I have a desktop connected to a UPS and would like the option to put the computer into hibernate (in case there is a power failure).

There is no "hibernate" option on the power menu. In an elevated command prompt I ran `powercfg/h` on and `powercfg/hibernate on` and it made no difference. In the advanced power settings, I changed the "hibernate after" from "never" to "0" but it didn't do anything. How can I have an option to manually put the computer into hibernation?

Answer (score 3):

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> and type in `power options`.
2. Select the `Power Options` in `Control Panel` option.
3. In the `Power Options` window, click `Choose what the power buttons do` from the left menu.
4. This opens the `System Settings` screen, where there should be a `Shutdown settings` section towards the bottom.
5. Click the `Change settings that are currently unavailable` text to enable changing items in `Shutdown settings`.
6. Check the `Hibernate` box and save changes.

[image]